# How to run each feature file with scenarios on different chrome instances parallelly?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest, specflow

The Problem:

I am using **MSTest framework** for running UI tests. I have **10 feature files** **each** having at least **20 scenarios**. I am able to run them successfully using a pipeline, but it takes around **4-5 hours** to execute. So, I would like to split the testcases and run them on different chrome instances (I don't want to run it on different browsers) at the same time. (Note: I have only one agent)

Here is my **Repo structure**:

- Feature files

  - steps file

    - Page object model**

*Example:*

**Login.feature**

```
Scenario: Verify if user is able to login with valid credentials
    Given I have opened a web app in new browser
    And I have navigated to url
    When I enter valid credentials
    Then I should be signed in successfully

Scenario: Verify if user is able to login with invalid credentials
    Given I have opened a web app in new browser
    And I have navigated to url
    When I enter invalid credentials
    Then an error message regarding invalid credentials
```

**LoginSteps.cs**

```
[Given(@"I have opened a web app in new browser")]
public void OpenBrowser()
{
    _loginPage.OpenBrowser();
}

[Given(@"I have navigated to url")]
public void NavigateTo()
{
_loginPage.NavigateTo();
}

[When("I enter valid credentials")]
public void EnterCredentials()
{
    _loginPage.EnterCredentials();
}

[When("I enter invalid credentials")]
public void EnterInvalidCredentials()
{
    _loginPage.EnterInvalidCredentials();
}

[Then("I should be signed in successfully")]
public void SigninSucceessful()
{
    _loginPage.SigninSucceessful();
}

[Then("an error message regarding invalid credentials")]
public void SigninError()
{
    _loginPage.SigninError();
}
```

**LoginPOM.cs**

```
public void navigateTo()
{
   
}

public void OpenBrowser()
{
  //code to open chrome browser
}

public void EnterCredentials(){
 // Browser.sendkeys() used here
}
```

**Update:**
I have added ,

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers = 2, Scope=ExecutionScope.MethodLevel)];
```

in one of the step definition files. But I am getting the below **error**:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'ScenarioContext')
TestCleanup method TM.UserFunctionalTests.Features.InventoryFeature.TestTearDown threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
```

Here is the hooks.cs file

```
    using BoDi;
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
    using TM.Test.Core.DataContexts;
    using TM.Test.Core.Helpers;
    using TM.Test.Core.Setup;
    using TM.Test.Shared.Logging;
    
    namespace TM.Test.Shared.Hooks
    {
    [Binding]
    public class ScenarioHooks : TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps
    {
    private readonly TestContext _testContext;
    private readonly ScreenShotSteps _screenShotSteps;
    private readonly PerformanceInfoContext _startInfo;
    private readonly IObjectContainer _container;
    
    public ScenarioHooks(TestContext testContext, ScreenShotSteps screenShotSteps, PerformanceInfoContext startInfo, IObjectContainer container)
    {
    _testContext = testContext;
    _screenShotSteps = screenShotSteps;
    _startInfo = startInfo;
    _container = container;
    }
    
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
    try
    {
                    PInvoke.AllowSetForegroundWindow(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to do PInvoke -> {nameof(PInvoke.AllowSetForegroundWindow)}");
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    }
    
    [BeforeScenario(Order = int.MinValue)]
    public async Task BeforeScenarioAsync()
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"|||| Current CPU load: {_startInfo.GetCPULoad()}, available memory: {_startInfo.GetAvailableMemory()} ");
    
    await _testContext.SetUpNewScenarioRun();
    
    Console.WriteLine($"|||| Current CPU load: {_startInfo.GetCPULoad()}, available memory: {_startInfo.GetAvailableMemory()} ");
    Console.WriteLine("= SCENARIO: " + ScenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("= FEATURE: " + FeatureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
    
    
    //Initialize Serilog
    var logService = new LogService();
    _container.RegisterInstanceAs(logService, typeof(ILogService));
    }
    
    [AfterScenario(Order = int.MinValue)]
    public void AfterScenarioBeforeTearDown()
    {
    var lastError = ScenarioContext.TestError;
    var result = lastError == null ? "PASSED" : "FAILED";
    
    Console.WriteLine("EXECUTED SCENARIO: " + ScenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("EXECUTED FEATURE: " + FeatureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
    Console.WriteLine($"RESULTS OF EXECUTION: {result}");
    if (lastError != null)
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR MESSAGE: {lastError.Message}");
    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR SOURCE: {lastError.Source}");
    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR STACKTRACE: {lastError.StackTrace}");
    
    _screenShotSteps.TakeAScreenShotWithContextData();
    }
               
    //Dispose of Serilog
    var logService = _container.Resolve<ILogService>();
    logService.CloseAndFlush();
    }
    
    [AfterScenario(Order = int.MaxValue)]
    private async Task AfterScenarioTearDown()
    {
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    try
    {
    await _testContext.TearDownAfterScenarioRun();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Tear down time: {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:N1} seconds.");
    Debug.WriteLine($"Total scenario run time: {_testContext.ScenarioStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:N1} seconds.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Debug.WriteLine("Failed to tear down after scenario.");
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

I have noticed the issue is in cs file generated automatically for feature files. There for the function TestTearDown, it's throwing error.

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCleanupAttribute()]
        public void TestTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. Currently the exception message mentions something in the "teardown" of the test. It leads me to believe an `[AfterScenario]` hook is to blame, but I do not see that code in your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Sorry for the poor explanation. I have attached the hook.cs file for reference.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with SpecFlow. By the time you execute tests, they are just plain old MS Test classes and methods. SpecFlow just generates these classes from the feature file. You might get better results seeing if you can do this concurrently with MS Test.